# Angular: tsconfig "composite":true flag not working with libraries within a ng-workspace

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I've been trying to make this work, I have an NG16 workspace but whenever I use paths in my `tsconfig.lib.json`, the editor won't recognize the paths since it's not in the main `tsconfig.json`.

However, I've tried to implement the new https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html reference feature to link my tsconfig.lib.ts to my root tsconfig.json but it seems to always fail and never recognize the files defined in the 'include' pattern.

`File 'drive/x/y/z/workspace/projects/my-lib/src/lib/my-lib.module.ts' is not listed within the file list of project 'drive/x/y/z/workspaceprojects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.`

and

Building entry point '@workspace/my-lib

````
- Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.
× Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.
projects/my-lib/src/lib/test.service.ts:1:1 - error TS6307: File 'drive/x/y/z/workspace/projects/my-lib/src/lib/test.service.ngtypecheck.ts' is not listed within the file list of project 'drive/x/y/z/workspace/projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.

1

projects/my-lib/src/public-api.ts:6:29 - error TS6307: File 'drive/x/y/z/workspace/projects/my-lib/src/lib/test.service.ts' is not listed within the file list of project 'drive/x/y/z/workspace/projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.

6 export { TestService } from './lib/test.service';
`

See tsconfig.lib.json below

./projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json
```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [],
    "paths": { /* classified */ },
    "composite": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.stories.ts",
    "**/*.stories.js",
    "**/*.stories.ts",
    "**/*.stories.js"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Root tsconfig.json
```

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,

    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  },
}
````

I'm expecting of course a compiling library on ng build my-lib but instead it's giving some strange errors which I'm unable to resolve. Does anyone know what's going on? I've provided all the patterns in the include property